# UK Visitor visa - made a mistake on travel dates - is refusal likely?

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas

I applied for a Standard Visitor Visa on the 8th of May. Submitted biometrics the same day. I have had 4 previous UK visitor visas in the last 7 years.

I was just going through my application now (As the visa decision is delayed and figured I look at application again, anyway)

I noticed I put down that I will be there from 7th July to 27th August - 2023. When I meant to say 7th July to 27th July.

I supplied info to support a 3 week stay. And finances to prove I have 3000 GBP for the trip and that my British Wife and British Son will be traveling with me as we going to see family.

Now I am worried they will refuse this application - because perhaps finances are not enough and I said I am staying at one address in July only - as well as I didn't supply a leave approval letter from company for two months leave (As I am not staying that long)

Does this mean a refusal is almost a certainty?

I have also resigned from my company since making my application and accepted employment at a new company (Signed Contract and paper work to show this) - If they refuse it I want to add this info in as well as a letter from the new company confirming my employment again and the leave I am taking. Would this be okay or does that look more suspicious?

Comment: I don’t think anyone can answer this for sure. You have a good UK visa history but OTOH the documents you presented this time don’t seem to fully support the application. The former may outweigh the latter, or vice versa. You could consider cancelling the application rather than risking a refusal harming your travel history, depends on tour risk appetite I guess

Comment: Thanks. I had a refusal before in 2015 - and was able to overcome that with more documentation. I'm going to just wait it out and hope for the best. Will update this question with an answer, either way for anyone else in a similar situation.

Comment: I have no idea about the visa processing times at the consulate where you have applied, but since it is not *that* much time left until you plan to travel on July 7th, I am not so sure if it is a good idea to wait for a decision and then reapply if you are refused. As you have noticed, your application is already delayed and it is not unlikely that it has landed in a 'more thorough examination required' queue.

Comment: I believe I will have more than enough time to reapply if it comes back rejected. I'll pay for a priority service, which I believe gives a decision in 5 working days.

Comment: @Traveller I had a response to my paid enquiry to UKVI. They say a decision has been made, according to their records and if I am granted the visa it will be in the passport and that they can’t say more than that. Also says to wait on TLS. So I guess I’ll just wait and see what happened. Someone told me they do send our rejection emails these days but I don’t know how true that is.

Comment: @RobertJ.Clegg Good luck, hope it works out  :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Having added an extra month to my time in the UK by mistake on the forms were of no consequence in my application. I had provided documents to support a 3 week stay however mistakenly put in an extra month in the time I would be in the UK.

My visa was approved. I suspect this is due to good travel history (4 UK Visitor visas and a valid US visa still) and good financials / ties to home country shown.

Comment: or the requirements for a 7 week and a 3 week stay are approximately the same. Congratulations.

Comment: Maybe. However for where I was staying; I only gave them proof of a 3 week stay.